# Class for handling player movement and / or similar behaviour

Tags: c#, unity3d

I am currently developing a Unity-based multiplatform game (PC, iOS, Android) in a small team. This is the code we have created for the character actions inside the game. I am looking for feedback on the code itself as well as tips on how some Unity features could be used better. This is my first time developing a game with Unity.

The game is also aimed for mobile platforms as stated above, so tips on optimization are welcome.

```
using AI.Enemy;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Player.Script.Miru
{
    public class MiruScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public float Health;
    public float MoveSpeed;
    public float JumpHeight; 
    public float EvadeSpeed;
    public float DefendCooldownTimer;
    public float NormalDamage;
    public float Cooldown;
    public float Stamina;
    public float HealthRegenerationRate;
    public float StaminaRegenerationRate;

    private bool _IsFacingForward;
    private bool _IsGrounded;
    private Rigidbody2D _RigidBody;
    private RaycastHit2D _GroundDetector;
    private RaycastHit2D _RightRayCast;
    private RaycastHit2D _LeftRayCast;
    private MinionScript _MinionScript;

    private void Start() //Temporary values
    {
        MoveSpeed = 4f * Time.deltaTime;
        JumpHeight = 10f;
        EvadeSpeed = 5f;
        DefendCooldownTimer = 0f;
        NormalDamage = 50f;
        Cooldown = 1f;
        Stamina = 100f;
        Health = 100f;
        HealthRegenerationRate = 0.5f;
        StaminaRegenerationRate = 10f;
        _RigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _MinionScript = GetComponent<MinionScript>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        MoveRight(MoveSpeed);
        MoveLeft(MoveSpeed);
        Jump(JumpHeight);
        Evade(EvadeSpeed);
        Attack(NormalDamage);
        DistanceFromObject();
        AttackCooldown();
        Defend();
    }

    private bool AttackCooldown()
    {
        if (Cooldown < 1f)
        {
            Cooldown += Time.deltaTime;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int DamageDealt(float _damageDealt)
    {
        Health -= _damageDealt;

        if (Health <= 0)
            Destroy(gameObject);

        return 0;
    }

    private int DistanceFromObject()
    {
        _RightRayCast = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right);
        _LeftRayCast = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.left);

        if (_RightRayCast.distance < 1.5f && _LeftRayCast.distance < 1.5f)
            return 3;

        if (_RightRayCast.distance < 1.5f)
            return 1;

        if (_LeftRayCast.distance < 1.5f)
            return 2;

        return 0;
    }

    private int Attack(float _damageDealt)
    {
        if (_IsFacingForward && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X) && _RightRayCast.distance <= 1.5f && !AttackCooldown())
        {
            _MinionScript = _RightRayCast.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<MinionScript>();
            _MinionScript.DamageDealt(_damageDealt);
            Cooldown = 0;
            return 1;
        }

        if (_IsFacingForward == false && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X) && _LeftRayCast.distance <= 1.5f && !AttackCooldown())
        {
            _MinionScript = _LeftRayCast.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<MinionScript>();
            _MinionScript.DamageDealt(_damageDealt);
            Cooldown = 0;
            return 2;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private int MoveRight(float _moveSpeed)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && Defend() == 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(_moveSpeed, 0, 0);
            _IsFacingForward = true;
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private int MoveLeft(float _moveSpeed)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && Defend() == 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(-_moveSpeed, 0, 0);
            _IsFacingForward = false;
            return 1;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    private int Jump(float _height)
    {
        _GroundDetector = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.down);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z) && _IsGrounded)
        {
            _RigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * _height, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            return 1;
        }

        if (_GroundDetector.distance > 0.6f)
        {
            _IsGrounded = false;
            return 2;
        }

        _IsGrounded = true;
        return 0;
    }

    private int Evade(float _evadeSpeed)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _IsGrounded)
            switch (DistanceFromObject())
            {
                case 1:
                    _RigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * _evadeSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                    _RigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.left * _evadeSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                    return 1;

                case 2:
                    _RigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * _evadeSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                    _RigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.right * _evadeSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                    return 2;

                case 3:
                    _RigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * _evadeSpeed * 3, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                    return 3;
            }

        return 0;
    }

    private int Defend()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && _IsGrounded)
        {
            DefendCooldownTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (DefendCooldownTimer >= 0.5f)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else
            DefendCooldownTimer = 0f;

        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Magic numbers like 0, 1, 2 and 3 returned by `DistanceFromObject` are difficult to read and are easily mixed up. Use an `enum` instead.

```
[Flags]
private enum Proximity
{
    None = 0,
    Right = 1,
    Left = 2,
    LeftAndRight = Left | Right
}

// A constant allows you to change the value easily.
private const float ProximityLimit = 1.5f;

private Proximity DistanceFromObject()
{
    _RightRayCast = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.right);
    _LeftRayCast = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, Vector2.left);

    if (_RightRayCast.distance < ProximityLimit && _LeftRayCast.distance < ProximityLimit)
        return Proximity.LeftAndRight;

    if (_RightRayCast.distance < ProximityLimit)
        return Proximity.Right;

    if (_LeftRayCast.distance < ProximityLimit)
        return Proximity.Left;

    return Proximity.None;
}
```

The `Evade` method becomes easier to read.

```
private Proximity Evade(float _evadeSpeed)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && _IsGrounded) {
        Proximity proximity = DistanceFromObject();
        switch (proximity) {
            case Proximity.Right:
                _RigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * _evadeSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                _RigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.left * _evadeSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                break;

            case Proximity.Left:
                _RigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * _evadeSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                _RigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.right * _evadeSpeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                break;

            case Proximity.LeftAndRight:
                _RigidBody.AddForce(Vector2.up * _evadeSpeed * 3, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                break;
        }
        return proximity;
    }

    return Proximity.None;
}
```

Corresponding refactorings can be applied to `Attack` and `Jump`

In places where Unity requires you to use an `int` (I'm not a Unity developer), at least use constants.

```
const int NoProximity = 0, RightProximity = 1, ...;
```

Comment: Special thumbs-up for defining `Proximity.None`.  For enums generally always do this. Then enum variables must be explicitly set, reducing potential bugs from "blindly set" to valid but possibly wrong values.  Consider  a switch `default`. First as a general principle but also this can help catch errors when adding new enums and/or extensive editing, especially with "large"  enums.  It would not be the first time a "cannot ever happen" error had been caught.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not a Unity coder so this is C#-focused feedback, Unity might change some things or have different conventions. Apologies if I cause confusion as a result.

**Prefer properties over fields** and **prefer encapsulation** (i.e avoid public setters), for example `public float Health { get; private set; }`. Currently, any other code in your game can set the `Health` to whatever it wants, when it should be calling DamageDealt() and letting the object work out its own health!

The private method `Start()` appears not to be called at all, though perhaps Unity works some reflection magic to call it? In any case, **prefer inline initialization**, for example `private Rigidbody2D _RigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();`. This may not always be appropriate (e.g. if members need different starting values depending how they are constructed) but used properly means the object can immediately be in a valid state as soon as it is created.

**Avoid "magic numbers"** - another answer has already mentioned enums over ints, but the same applies for other constants. For example `private const float MaxHealth = 100f;` then later `Health = MaxHealth;` gives more meaning to what's going on. It also means that if the same value is used in multiple places (such as the repeated appearance of 1.5f in `DistanceFromObject` and `Attack`) and you later decide it needs to change, you only need to change it in one place if you have `private const float CheckDistance = 1.5f;` - otherwise, can you guarantee you wouldn't miss changing it somewhere? Finally, it gives you the flexibility in future to change constants to variables - perhaps you decide your game has Easy/Normal/Hard difficulty levels, you could make `MaxHealth` a static variable and change how much health the player starts with, for example.

Personally I'd put `MoveRight()` and `MoveLeft()` into a single `Move()` method. It'd be a bit clearer that way, and would mean `Defend` need only be called once, and the result stored. (It's currently possible for it to be called by both methods, so the `DefendCooldownTimer` will be incremented twice if left arrow, right arrow, and space are all pressed. Is that intentional?) In fact I wonder if it might be appropriate for all the code that checks input to be in the same method, because it checks for different key presses in different places at the moment and that's not very clear. However, there's a danger that approach could end up with a giant method that tries to do everything, which would be just as bad (and which you currently avoid).

Comment: The Start() method is called automatically by Unity upon initialization. Some unity classes, methods and others can only be called inside Start().

Comment: OK, fair enough, I wondered if that might be the case. That being the case, initialise inline when you can, or in Start() when you have to.